# Reseting panzoom should set the graph in original state in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

As given    https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-panzoom
 when I drag any node to any position and again zoom it and reset(i.e.fit to screen) that zoom using reset button,the draged node remains at new position where it is droped,it only fits the graph.
Is it possible to reset the graph to original state? i.e. if I move node to any position then after reset(fit to screen) it should appear at its original state/position.
I have used    layout{
name: 'cola'
} to layout the graph.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to reset the graph to its original position, I put this in cytoscape.js-panzoom.js. code as below:

```
                    $reset.bind("mousedown", function(e){
                    if( e.button != 0 ){
                        return;
                    }var cy = $container.cytoscape("get");
                    if( cy.elements().size() === 0 ){
                        cy.reset();
                    } else { coseOptions = {
                          name: 'cola', //set layout
                          ready               : function() {},
                          stop                : function() {},
                          refresh             : 0,
                          animate              : false,
                          fit                 : true, 
                          padding             : 30, 
                          randomize           : false,
                          debug               : false,
                          nodeRepulsion       : 10000,
                          nodeOverlap         : 10,
                          idealEdgeLength     : 10,
                          edgeElasticity      : 100,
                          nestingFactor       : 5, 
                          gravity             : 250, 
                          numIter             : 100,
                          initialTemp         : 200,
                          coolingFactor       : 0.95, 
                          minTemp             : 1
                        };
                   cy.layout(coseOptions);
                       //cy.fit( options.fitPadding );
                    }

                    return false;
                });
```